# Hibernate Envers undo

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

my application is working fine. But now the customer wants to undo changes.
Already made database commits have to be undo.

Therefore I have set up envers and enabled the two neccessary properties

```
    <property name="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision">true</property>
    <property name="org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag">true</property>
```

The Audit tables are created and filled automatically.
Now my listener (CTRL+Z) executes the following snipped

```
public void run() {

    if (SystemDatabaseManager.isInitialized()) {

        if (AppHelper.showQuestion(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), "undo?") == SWT.YES) {

            Session session = null;

            try {

                session = SystemDatabaseManager.getCurrentSession();

                AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);

                final Number revision = reader.getRevisionNumberForDate(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));

                List<Object> test = reader.getCrossTypeRevisionChangesReader().findEntities(revision);

                session.beginTransaction();
                for(Object object: test) {

                    session.merge(object);

                }
                SystemDatabaseManager.commit(session);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                SystemDatabaseManager.rollback(session);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Now the problem is merging the old object state throws an Exception

"Deleted object whould be resaved ..."

I know this Exception and what it stands for but I do not know how to solve it in this way.

The big problem is that not only primitive fields are changing. Also relations are changed.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with SQL. The audit tables are structurally the same as the normal tables, except for some additional data (version, date, time, etc.) Simply overwriting the record in the normal table with the record in the audit table would do the trick. All relations and related entities will have a corresponding record in the same version, so those should also be copied.

What does the customer mean when they want to undo a change?

- Do they want a **new** record in the audit table with the **previous** data, so the history of the undo is also preserved? This becomes more tricky, since you would have to insert a new record in the audit table and increment the global version number (insert a row in the revision table).
- Do they want to **rewind the system** to the previous state (erasing later audit records)? Now you would have to delete some records from the audit tables and also from the revision table.

The last solution is only save when you delete all version after a given version number.